# Product of two smooth functions that is identically zero

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

assume I am given with two smooth functions $f,g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ for which:
$$
f(x)\cdot g(x)=0 
$$ 
for every $x\in[a,b]$ .

Does this imply $f\equiv 0$ or $g\equiv 0$ on some subinterval $(m,n)\subseteq [a,b] $?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your equality implies that $f$ is zero where $g$ is not and vice-versa. Can you construct two smooth functions $f$ and $g$ that have this property and are not both identically $0$?

Comment: For your new question, let $x_0\in [a,b]$. Then one of $\{f,g\}$ is nonzero at $x_0$. Assume without loss of generality it is $f$. By the continuity of $f$, it is nonzero on an open around $x_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no...for an example consider a bump function $f$ with compact support $[a,a+b/2]$ and $g$ with compact support $[a+b/2,b]$...then then $f.g=0$ but none of these are identically 0.

for your edited version....this is true because if $f$ is not identically zero in any interval then let for some $m\in [a,b]$ $f(m) \neq 0$ then $f$ is not zero in a nbd of $m$ (by continuity) but $f.g=0$ in that nbd so $g$ has to be identically zero in that nbd.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I wasn't clear enough - I will state it otherwise:

In the conditions I stated, is it necessary that there will exist a subinterval $(m,n)\subseteq [a,b] $ for which one of the functions vanishes? 

Thanks a lot !

Comment: this will help you